# Compiling big header files leads to Compiler is out of heap space in pass 2 error

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, compilation

This question has been asked lot of times before but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I created a header file for my decision tree which looks like this

```
class PredictClass0 : public CompiledTree
{
public:
PredictClass0(const std::string& modelDirectory) :
    CompiledTree(20, 17, modelDirectory)
    {
    }
std::size_t predict_probabilities(const gst::ShottonFeatureAlgorithm &algorithm, const GstFrame* const frame, const std::size_t pixel,const std::vector<ParamValues>& offsetThresholdPair)
{
        if (algorithm.computeFeature(frame,pixel,offsetThresholdPair[0].offsetPairs) < offsetThresholdPair[0].threshold)
        {
            if (algorithm.computeFeature(frame,pixel,offsetThresholdPair[1].offsetPairs) < offsetThresholdPair[1].threshold)
            {
                if (algorithm.computeFeature(frame,pixel,offsetThresholdPair[2].offsetPairs) < offsetThresholdPair[2].threshold)
                {
                    if (algorithm.computeFeature(frame,pixel,offsetThresholdPair[3].offsetPairs) < offsetThresholdPair[3].threshold)

//and the list goes on....
```

The header file has a size of 30MB and i have 3 of them and it takes 6 hours to compile(error in the end). I have tried to minimize the amount of symbols and expressions as much as i can. So far i have tried these solutions:

- [MSDN Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9e6fs6b.aspx)
- Setting compiler flag /MP (Multiprocessor compilation)
- Compiler memory allocation /Zm
- Enable minimal build /Gm
- Setting Heap reserve and commit size to 10000000

Tried all these on a Win 10 machine with 32GB RAM and around 64GB memory left on my SSD. I would like to know if there is a neat way to handle compiling of huge files?

Comment: Can you pre-compile the headers?

Comment: Yes, but the issue would still be there with large amounts of computations to do even if i use PCH.

Answer (score 0):

> Setting Heap reserve and commit size to 10000000

Why are you limiting heap to 10 MB?   Try upping that to 100 MB or even 500 MB.  You have plenty of memory available.

Comment: Thanks! Ok i will give it a try. But i was wondering why doesn't Visual Studio handle this internally ?

Comment: @MarKS:  Who knows?  Other compilers do.  But maybe there is a documentation flaw which gives the impression that one *should* provide a heap size.  What happens if you don't specify one?

Comment: Agree! As far as i know, the default heap size is set to 1MB in Visual studio 2013. But it is kinda dirty hack to set your own heap size when the compiler could use my available memory. Moreover, i have tested it without one, i get the same error.

Comment: i tried setting it to 500MB and 1GB but still didn't work. Not sure if it is a memory issue in my PC or file is too big to compile for VS2013 or Visual Studio just can't handle it. Ran out of all ideas to compile..sadly.

Comment: @MarKS:  Have you tried compiling with `g++`?  Maybe it can diagnose something to explain why `vs` chokes.

Comment: sorry for a delayed response. Yes! I have tried it with g++ before i decided to go with VS. With g++ it takes my whole 32GB memory and then switches to swap filling it up as well.

Comment: @MarKS:  Has this code *ever* compiled successfully on any compiler/platform?  Maybe there is an infinite loop in its structure...

Comment: i tried every different approach but i learnt too many symbols and expressions are still a nightmare for modern compilers. I managed to break the decision trees into smaller files sacrificing my run-time behavior. Thank you for all the suggestions.